# How to test connected component actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I can easily test my connected components using a fake store to guarantee that the correct props are passed to my presentational component.  However, I'm unable to test that the correct actions are being passed.

Here is my simple connected component:

```
import {createCustomer} from './customerActions';
// other imports 

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        title: 'New Customer',
    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {save: createCustomer}
)(CustomerForm);
```

And here is the test:

```
import * as customerActions from './customerActions';
// other imports 

describe('Container:NewCustomerContainer', function () {
    let sandbox, createCustomerStub;

    beforeEach(function () {
        sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
        createCustomerStub = sandbox.spy(customerActions, 'createCustomer'); // attempt to spy on the action that should be passed as a prop
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        sandbox.restore();
    });

    function setup() {
        const store = storeFake();
        return mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <NewCustomerContainer>
                    <div>foo</div>
                </NewCustomerContainer>
            </Provider>
        );
    }

    // this works fine
    it('should pass the correct props', function () {
        const wrapper = setup();
        const component = wrapper.find(CustomerForm);
        expect(component.prop('title')).to.equal('New Customer');
    });

    // this fails
    it('should pass createCustomer as the save prop', function() {
        const wrapper = setup();
        const component = wrapper.find(CustomerForm);
        // call the prop action to see if the correct method was called
        component.prop('save')({});
        // error, stub method wasn't called. The REAL createCustomer is called instead
        expect(createCustomerStub.called).to.be.true; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The component is provisioned `createCustomer` as the following

```
import {createCustomer} from './customerActions';
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {save: createCustomer}
)(CustomerForm);
```

, which invokes essentially the `createCustomer` itself  when `save` is called, not the spy. There is no evaluation `customerActions.createCustomer` invoked at the time. The created spy does spy on the function, but never gets consulted.

The test set below provisions the component the spy, not the original `createCustomer` function. Both test cases pass.

```
const App = () => <div>App</div>;
const mapStateToProps = () => { return { title: 'New Customer' }; };
const customerActions = {
  createCustomer() { return { type: 'CREATE_CUSTOMER' }; }
};

describe('Container:NewCustomerContainer', function() {
  let sandbox, createCustomerStub, component;

  beforeEach(function() {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    createCustomerStub = sandbox.spy(customerActions, 'createCustomer');

    const ConnectedApp = connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      {save: customerActions.createCustomer}
    )(App);

    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={createStore(() => {})}>
        <ConnectedApp />
      </Provider>
    );
    component = wrapper.find(App);
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should pass the correct props', function() {
    expect(component.prop('title')).to.equal('New Customer');
  });

  it('should pass createCustomer as the save prop', function() {
    component.prop('save')();
    expect(createCustomerStub.called).to.be.true;⋅
  });
});
```

Comment: These tests do pass, however, they are not testing that the connected component is passed the correct action creator for the `save` method.  It is only testing the save method that you pass in the test.

Comment: That's is what the erred test case in the OP is for, and that's what a test spy is for. A spy is not a replacement of the spied function. It is a recorder recording what's happening when the spied function is called.